# Does this NullPointerException refer to getFoos returning null or some problem with the cast from a Collection to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, collections, casting, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Why does this line cause a `NullPointerException`:

```
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>(userDetailsService.getFoos(currentUser));
```

The `getFoos` method simply returns a `Collection` of `Foo`s:

```
    public Collection<Foo> getFoos(final String username)
```

I can't tell if the `NullPointerException` refers to `getFoos` returning `null` or some problem with the cast from a `Collection` to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: -1 for not posting the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the stacktrace. Head to the first line. If it points to `java.util.ArrayList.<init>`, then `getFoos()` has returned `null`. Or if it points to the particular line in your question, then `userDetailsService` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't tell if the
>   NullPointerException refers to getFoos
>   returning null or some problem with
>   the cast from a Collection  to an
>   ArrayList.

And that's why we have the [Law of Demeter](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). If you separate the two statements that have been conjoined together, you would have better luck in resolving the issue.

However, it should be apparent that a null collection (not an empty collection) is returned which is responsible for the issue. After all, invoking the ArrayList constructor with a null collection will not result in a null pointer exception.

**EDIT**:

My bad. The ArrayList constructor will attempt to copy the collection. So a null collection can cause a null pointer exception. I stick to my original recommendation of decoupling the two statements. Coding in the following manner will help identify the issue faster:

```
Collection<Foo> myFoos = userDetailsService.getFoos(currentUser);
List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>(myFoos);
```

Comment: Fully agree with splitting the statement into 2 separate statements. Should then make it obvious which is failing.

Answer (score 0):

A failed typecast cannot give you a `NullPointerException`.

```
Object o = new Integer(43);
String s = (String) o;  // throws ClassCastException
```

Typecasting a `null` will not throw an exception at all.

```
o = null;
String s = (String) o;  // no exception
```

Therefore the theory that `getFoo` is returning a `null` is plausible.  But it could also be that `userDetailsService` is `null` or that the NPE is thrown in `getFoo`.

You should be able to distinguish these cases by **carefully** reading the stacktrace ... which you didn't include in your question (tsk, tsk).